# How to put this command in a Makefile?

Tags: awk, makefile, docker

I have the following command I want to execute in a `Makefile` but I'm not sure how.
The command is `docker rmi -f $(docker images | grep "<none>" | awk "{print \$3}")`

The command executed between `$(..)` should produce output which is fed to `docker rmi` but this is not working from within the `Makefile` I think that's because the `$` is used specially in the `Makefile` but I'm not sure how to modify the command to fit in there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` in Makefiles needs to be doubled to prevent substitution by `make`:

```
docker rmi -f $$(docker images | grep "<none>" | awk "{print \$$3}")
```

Also, it'd be simpler to use  use a singly-quoted string in the `awk` command to prevent expansion of `$3` by the shell:

```
docker rmi -f $$(docker images | grep "<none>" | awk '{print $$3}')
```

I really recommend the latter. It's usually better to have `awk` code in single quotes because it tends to contain a lot of `$`s, and all the backslashes hurt readability.